# Can you aggregate SUM etc as the same type?

Tags: postgresql, redshift

In PG and RedShift when you aggregate an int4 column, it's returned as an int8 column, makes perfect sense but how can you keep the types? For example:

```sql
SELECT SUM(int4_colum) AS int8_column FROM foo;
```

Now you can can explicitly recast:

```sql
SELECT SUM(int4_colum)::int AS int4_column FROM foo;
```

But that means coupling a lot of query logic to the underlying type, which is a maintenance nightmare. Is it not possible to do:

```sql
SELECT CAST(SUM(int4_colum) AS int4_column) AS int4_column FROM foo;
```

I understand I can query it from system tables like `PG_TABLE_DEF`, but then you run into subqueries and CTE's and the need to lookup schema information rather than being able to dynamically handle it.

Is there a solution here?

Comment: *how can you keep the types?* 1) Noway. 2) Always explicit datatype convertion when the datatype is not suitable or clear. *which is a maintenance nightmare.* I think backward - indefinite implicitly set datatype is a nightmare.